# Can make drupal multiple content type on same page?

Tags: drupal-7, field, content-type

I have 2 content type with different fields , can i display this 2 content type on one page to be completed by the user in the same page, i think to make a master content type with filed collection of that 2 content type, but i don't know what is the best practice for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Drupal Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) for displaying fields from more than one content type.